# Alfresco management Site

Tags: alfresco, sites

Use Alfresco 5.2.0

I have some problems managing my sites.

When I try to create a new site I get the message:

```
Failed to execute script 'classpath *: alfresco / templates / webscripts / org / alfresco / slingshot / sites / site-identifier-used.get.js': No enum constant org.alfresco.service.cmr.site.SiteVisibility.public
```

If I access Administration Tools -> Sites, the message that appears to me is:

```
04180082 Wrapped Exception (with status template): No enum constant org.alfresco.service.cmr.site.SiteVisibility.public
```

Can anyone give me an idea of what may be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Could you search and show to us more logs from the **catalina.out** file located in your *Tomcat* log files?
I think there are some other errors.